# Enable logging for API calls in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 Identity server and trying to add a service provider XML file with federated configuration however federated identity provider is not set up in my wso2.

I see the error response code in my application as below:

```
 {"response": "{\"code\":\"APP-xxxxx\",\"message\":\"Error importing application from XML file.\",\"description\":\"Federated Identity Provider test is not available in the server.\",\"traceId\":\"xxxxxxxxxxx\"}"}
```

I see this log in the application which is trying to post the xml file to wso2 API to add the service provider however I dont see any log related to this in wso2 identity server logs.

I just see a log which shows service provider is added and than deleted immediately.

How do I enable API call logs in wso2 IS so that the error response can be recorded in wso2 logs as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the log4j2.properties file in your WSO2 IS installation directory.

You can change the logging level of the API or specific components to DEBUG or TRACE for more detailed logs.

```
logger.org-wso2-carbon-identity level = DEBUG
```

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.1.0/deploy/monitor/work-with-product-observability/#log4j-configs